# $\sum _{k = 0}^ n \binom ka \binom {n-k}b = \binom {n+1}{a+b+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

$\sum _{k = 0}^ n \binom ka \binom {n-k}b = \binom {n+1}{a+b+1} $

Can anyone please give me a hint to prove it using combinatorics ? I know that $n \geq a+b$ and $k$ will run from $a$ to $n-b$ . But I think it should be $\binom {n}{a+b} $.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: My answer at the earlier question sketches a combinatorial proof. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942437/combinatorial-approach-to-a-binomial-sum-identity).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Consider choosing $a+b+1$ objects from a total of $n+1$ such that there are $a$ objects before and $b$ objects after the $(k+1)^{st}$ object.

Comment: Please explain more. I did not get you.@cosmo5

Comment: This is counting in two ways. LHS indicates picking two items at once. So we created a situation in which expression on LHS matches that on RHS. See other answers also, since this question is actually a duplicate.